# How to remove the type (number|undefined)[] to number[] in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript, after passing array of objects into map, I am getting (number|undefined)[] and I need to pass array of type numbers[] to underlying functions, how to convert (number|undefined)[] into number[]

Here is what I tried

```
interface Person {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    city: string;
}

let personObj:Person[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        city: 'LA'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Bob',
        city: 'CA'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Carl',
        city: 'CA'
    },
]

let objIds = personObj.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.city == 'CA') {
        return obj.id;
    }
})
```

type of objIds is (number|undefined)[] but we want the return type of objIds to be just number[],
I tried to use filter like this

```
let objIds = personObj.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.city == 'CA') {
        return obj.id;
    }
}).filter((ids) => {
    if (ids != undefined) {
        return ids;
    }
})

doSomething(objIds) and I need objIds to be number[]
```

But still type of objIds is (number|undefined)[], Can someone please help me how to correct type for objIds?

Comment: Why not filter and *then* map? https://tsplay.dev/NavLBm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.filter` does not filter types. Here are some alternative options:

1. Assert the type

```
let objIds = personObj.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.city == 'CA') {
        return obj.id;
    }
}).filter((ids) => {
    if (ids != undefined) {
        return ids;
    }
}) as number[];
```

2. Use [ts-reset](https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset). This is a library that will do some tweaks to TypeScript, one of which is changing the types for `Array.filter(Boolean)`

```
import "@total-typescript/ts-reset";

let objIds = personObj.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.city == 'CA') {
        return obj.id;
    }
}).filter(Boolean); // Does the same as your original behavior
```

3. Use the lodash [`_.compact()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#compact) method. This functions like `Array.filter(boolean)` but handles types automatically.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

let objIds = _.compact(personObj.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.city == 'CA') {
        return obj.id;
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

as pink comments, in your case first filtering for CA and then mapping to get the Id will perfectly work.
If you have a different situation, where you can't get rid of the undefined elements in the array, you will have to go for a typeguard. The https://www.benmvp.com/blog/filtering-undefined-elements-from-array-typescript/ describes this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the typescript can narrow types with `.filter` right now. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) for an ongoing discussion & workarounds.

Edit: See the other answer, filtering before using map will work in your case.

Comment: No, you can, but you need a type predicate.